# Java Pattern What is the issue with these pattern match?

Tags: java, regex

I would like a java pattern match a series of non-whitespace character followed or not by a series of whitespace character, the followed by a pair of parenthesis containing anything within with this code:

```
        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[^\\s+][\\s*]\\({1}[.*]\\){1}");
```

however, when I tried to match it with "a (a)", false is returned.

Maybe similar problems:

two websites saparated by white spaces:

```
Pattern p4 = Pattern.compile("([^\\s+]([\\.]{1}[^\\s+])+)[\\s+]([^\\s+]([\\.]{1}[^\\s+])+)");
```

Two strings of non-whitespace character separated by certain list of punctuation or words present in the code below (ex. and, or, aka...) (it could start with the list of words).

```
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(
            "([^\\s+][\\s+])?([and|or|aka|&amp;|Related to|moved from|now|formerly|and by the same host|and any address starting with]{1}[\\s+][^\\s+])+");


Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("[^\\s]+[\\s*][,|&amp;|;|\\s+/|/\\s+]{1}[\\s*][^\\s+]");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think reading the [docs on patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) in java might be helpful

Particular issue is that you put `+` and `*` to wrong place but I think the reason is that you don't understand what `[something]` means. The following code

```
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[^\\s]+[\\s]*\\({1}.*\\){1}");
    //Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[^\\s]+[\\s]*\\(.*\\)"); //simplified same pattern
    String t = "a (a)";
    Matcher matcher = p1.matcher(t);
    System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

prints true.

Answer (score 0):

`[^\\s]+[\\s]*\\(.*?\\)`

Will do what you want. Move the asterisk and plus sign outside the *character class* brackets. Both instances of `{1}` do nothing. With no other quantifier, tokens are repeated one time and finally `[.*]` in the case of those two characters literally means `permit one of these two characters`

`[test]` means one of t, e, or s. The second t is irrelevant. Most characters inside character classes mean their literal counterpart, but the exceptions involve a lot more explaining than should be done in an S/O answer.

Not that while this will succeed for say `a (b)`, this will give unexpected results if you have two occurences to match in the same sentence and is generally just a messy expression.

For a realistic expression, you need to provide realistic sample data.

An exceptional resource, after learning the basics, is the realtime testing environments provided by sites like http://regex101.com with syntax highlighting, match highlighting, match breakdown, and tooltips on mouseover of tokens, it's a great way to take the second step. While it only supports a few (commonly used) flavors, most mature programming/scripting languages share the same basic/intermediate capabilities in regex.